# What to do with Tag Wiki excerpts that love their subject a bit much?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I have seen several tag Wiki edits in the edit queue that are *very* enthusiastic in tone bordering advertising, and usually don't add real value to the Wiki.

A random example that I just saw in the queue (relatively harmless compared to others I've seen, but I didn't write those down, and I'm too lazy to do the research right now): [WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3897620/revisions)

Now this is well-intentioned, and not really *harmful* as such. Maybe I'm being too harsh altogether, but I'm not thrilled about project-and product-related tag wikis becoming a billboard for fans. I would like to see some Wikipedia-Style neutrality here.

Are there any guidelines for this? All I can see on Meta is more general stuff like this [list of tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59415).

Comment: Now that we have a Wordpress.SE, the [wordpress] tag wiki excerpt should contain some brief guidance on which questions to post on Stack Overflow, and which questions to post on Wordpress.SE.

Comment: [apache] looks like another example.  The excerpt is a mini-biography for the Apache Foundation, but the tag's questions appear to be talking about the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple.

If it feels to you like it is "selling" something and not concisely describing the tag with critical information.

#### [Edit It](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3897620/revisions)

An edit that improves an excerpt will most likely be approved, additionally the widening of the group of people with full tag wiki rights means that we can get a better objective view.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way to edit tag-wiki's whilst they are in the review queue.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's ok for tag wikis to sometimes not be NPOV on Stack Overflow..

The goal is to briefly say what the tag is about, not to be an "encyclopedia" like wikipedia. If people want more information they can look it up elsewhere, the tag wiki isn't the best place for that.

Comment: Fair points. Unless it's *really* excessive, I guess it's okay