# Tag wiki edits adding subjective opinions

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do with Tag Wiki excerpts that love their subject a bit much?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78433/what-to-do-with-tag-wiki-excerpts-that-love-their-subject-a-bit-much)

I was just prompted to approve/reject an edit of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio/info which added:

> It is a powerful IDE that ensures quality code throughout the entire application lifecycle, from design to deployment.

I rejected it as marketing fluff, but it already had one vote to approve.  Is that an appropriate statement to include in any tag wiki?  That particular tag is already sponsored so it hardly needs additional salesmanship.

If somehow it is approved (and I would not be surprised by collusion if someone is trying to game the tag wikis) is there some way to flag it?

Permalink to edit suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/71330

Comment: *"that **strives** to assure "*... Or "attempts" or "seeks".

Comment: Heh, propose an edit anonymously, then log in as a regular user and cast the first approving vote... nice way to spam the system with promotional crap. Can the mods track who cast the first vote to ensure they have no obvious affiliation with the tag (or product on the tag)?