# Is there a standard format for Tag Wikis?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

EDIT : So, this is the best *resource* that there is https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59418/200868 I think that we need to create a more detailed post rather than refer to an answer that was written 2 years ago, probably at the time tag wikis were implemented. There is much more data available now, many more samples, and many more sites.

---

Tag wikis vary greatly within sites and from site to site.

- Is there any standard format that they should follow ?
- What content should they ideally have ?
- Should they delve into directly related topics (when highly relevant) ?

Comment: Probable duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62445/212576

Comment: @hjpotter92 I would hardly think of a one vote post with low views as a *standard format*

Comment: Please check the comment on that reply.

Comment: @hjpotter92 None cover the third part of my question. Also, they are pretty vague on format.

Comment: Right, we don't have one yet. The other question is asking if we should have one. You're asking if there is one. Same kinda thingy.

Comment: So, this is the best *resource* that there is http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59418/200868 . I think that we need to create a more detailed post rather than refer to an answer that was written 2 years ago, probably near the time wikis were implemented. There is much more data, many more samples, many more sites now.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the excerpt, please keep it short.  Most excerpts should just start with the word "is", so you would start reading with the tag, like "[sql](/questions/tagged/sql) is ...".